# What are sequences in the csv reader and writer in python?

Tags: python

""The csv module’s reader and writer objects read and write sequences what are sequences"" from https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. What are the sequences here? and why does the including [] and [[ ]] in the writerow function alter the behavior of writing to the csv files?

Comment: Any reason why you are referring to Python2 documentation here? If you don't have a restriction, please consider using python 3 .

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence in python is anything over which you can iterate. Most of the python datatypes are iterable. Examples are `list`, `tuple`, and `str`.

About the difference between `[]` and `[[ ]]`:
Both are lists. But the second one is a list containing another list.

Let's say `x = [1,2,3]` .Then the sequence x has three members.
Now let's consider another list y = [x].This list `y` contains *one* item - the `list x`.
So `y` is `[ [1,2,3] ]`. If you pass that, your csv row will have a single item, where as with `[1,2,3]` you will have three items.